# Hoc Hof syntax on typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I got `TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'UIBuilderForm'.` exception.

I was trying to apply HoC (high order component) on `UIBuilderForm`

What's the correct way to use this syntax on typescript with ES6?

```
    class UIBuilderForm extends React.Component<any, {}> {
        ...
    }


    let UIBuilderForm :any = reduxForm({
        form: FORM_NAME
    })(UIBuilderForm as any);

    const selector = formValueSelector(FORM_NAME) //

    let UIBuilderForm = connect(
        formStates
    )(UIBuilderForm)

    ??? UIBuilderForm = connect(
        mapStateToProps,
        mapDispatchToProps
    )(UIBuilderForm)


    export default UIBuilderForm
```

Comment: You just need to name your new thing something else, the error is because you reuse the same name for the original component and the result of your `reduxForm` and `connect` calls.

Comment: The assignment even would've worked, you just need to omit the `let` declaration.

Answer (score 1):

You have two `let` and one `class` declaration for the same variable name, which isn't allowed. Either choose different names, or omit the `let`s:

```
class UIBuilderForm extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    ...
}

UIBuilderForm = reduxForm({
    form: FORM_NAME
})(UIBuilderForm);

const selector = formValueSelector(FORM_NAME) //

UIBuilderForm = connect(
    formStates
)(UIBuilderForm)

UIBuilderForm = connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(UIBuilderForm)

export default UIBuilderForm;
```

Or just put everything in one big expression:

```
const selector = formValueSelector(FORM_NAME);

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(connect(
    formStates
)(reduxForm({
    form: FORM_NAME
})(class UIBuilderForm extends React.Component<any, {}> {
    ...
})));
```